# I m very new to magento. Can you please tell me? How can i delete configurable product attributes that i have marked in image

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, delete, magento2.3.2

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am using Magento 2.3.2. I want to delete those two attributes that I have marked. I googled it but did not find any solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJULS.png - store->Attributes->Products
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vYgS.png - on product page configuration section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go To **Store->Attributes->Product** here find your attribute and edit, in edit screen there will be a button to delete.

Comment: I did not find any of the attribute there I had tried this before. If there is any other option please let me know.

Comment: I have mentioned second image of Location(Store->Attributes->Product). It is showing some attribute but not what i had created in product configuration section.

Comment: tried search with attribute code?

Comment: Yes at that location, under Attribute Code there is a box, add attribute code there and press *Enter*

Comment: Sorry I got the attribute. Thanks for your time.